# Equality between Isabelle terms that use SOME

Tags: isabelle

I'm a little surprised that

```
value "let x = SOME n. n ∈ {1::int,2} in x = x"
```

returns `True`. After β-expanding and α-renaming, that term is the same as:

```
value "(SOME na. na ∈ {1::int,2}) = (SOME nb. nb ∈ {1::int,2})"
```

I don't see why this equality should hold. Why should the value chosen for `na` be the same as the value chosen for `nb`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The term on the left hand side is exactly the same as the term on the right hand side (modulo alpha conversion). Therefore, they also have the same value. Equal (or rather alpha-equivalent) terms always produce equal values in HOL, since it is deterministic.

You can think of `SOME x. P x` giving you an arbitrary, but fixed value for which the property `P` holds (if such a value exists, otherwise just some arbitrary but fixed value about which you know nothing at all). In particular, different “calls” of SOME with the same argument will always give you the same value. The same is true of `THE`, `undefined`, and so on.

If you want true nondeterministic choice, you have to either use a different logic or model nondeterminism within HOL. The Refinement Framework offers a nondeterministic monad in which every operation can have zero, one, or many possible results.

Comment: Thanks Manuel, this all makes good sense to me. It's this idea of "arbitrary, but fixed" that I keep forgetting!